# Bond-line structure of 2-methyl-3-phenyl-1-butanol

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, molecular-structure

[image: 2-methyl-3-phenyl-1-butanol]

According to me the structure of 2-methyl-3-phenyl-1-butanol is the above one.

Is my answer correct?

Comment: only that the systematic name is 2-methyl-3-phenylbutan-1-ol

Answer (score -1):

You are correct the bond-line structure of 2-methyl-3-phenyl-1-butanol is the same as you you draw in the question you can even confirm it on

- [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/14089586#section=Top)
- [ChemSpider](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.9280837.html)